# Magento: Append block to before_body_end

Tags: magento

I'm wondering why the method given here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/3471 doesn't work for the xml block `<reference name="before_body_end"/>`?

I know the block type for before_body_end is core/text_list but Mage_Core_Block_Text still inherits Mage_Core_Block_Abstract which has the append method, so my understanding of Magento is that it should work, but I'm obviously missing something here?

**EDIT:**
This is an example of what is being attempted:

`<block type="core/template" name="myblock" template="path/to/myblock.phtml" />`

`<reference name="before_body_end">
    <action method="append" ifconfig="mymodule/settings/enabled">
         <block>myblock</block>
     </action>
</reference>`

Comment: could you please upload code for the same that you did so far ?

Comment: @sagarumaretiya does that mean that it should work?

Comment: I mean to say that please post whatever code you did with your question

Comment: Hi @sagarumaretiya, sorry for the delay; I've updated the original post with an example